# How to give column name for groupby value in PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

My dataset:

```
 - City_name
 - mumbai
 - kolkata
 - mangalore
 - mumbai
 - mumbai
 - kolkata
```

My code:

```
tot=data.groupby('City_name').size()
```

What I got:

```
 - City_name
 - kolkata        2
 - mangalore      1
 - mumbai         3
```

What I want:

```
 - City_name     Thefts
 - kolkata         2
 - mangalore     - 1
 - mumbai        - 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `reset_index`, and being a series you can also specify a `name` parameter:

```
df.groupby('City_name').size().reset_index(name='theft')

   City_name  theft
0    kolkata      2
1  mangalore      1
2     mumbai      3
```